# How can I increase the Match Rate on Admob?

Tags: admob

My Admob Ad Requests have gone up about 30% this year for [Vidalingua](http://vidalingua.com) dictionary apps.

However, during the same time, the Match Rate has gone down from above 97% to below 89%.

Is there anything I can do as a developer to increase the Match Rate?

Comment: Have you got any solution? If so, please share. I am facing same problem.

Comment: My match rate has crept back up to 92% but I'm at a loss to explain why, I've asked Google as well and they haven'ts been able to explain either, making me wonder if it's not driven by an algorithm.

Comment: Will it increase if I add some mediation ad network? what do you think?

Comment: I am testing Smaato because it doesn't require an SDK but I haven't verified any effect on the match rate.